# BrowseForFolder return error if directory is Desktop path

Tags: excel, vba

Below code is use to allow user to navigate directory, it works well if the location is a folder and failed if output directory is Desktop path. When I debug it show me the error on 'PickFolder = f.Items.Item.Path'. The error message is Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. Any idea how could I rewrite the code in order to fix this ? Thanks

```
Public Function PickFolder() As String
Dim SA As Object, f As Object
Dim OutputPath As String

'Ensure user has enter business date value before process PickFolder function
If BDTextBox.Text <> "" Then
Set SA = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set f = SA.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", _
     16 + 32 + 64)
If (Not f Is Nothing) Then
PickFolder = f.Items.Item.Path
OutputPath = PickFolder

FinalFileName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
'InStrRev will find the last occurrence of a character in a string. Search for \ and split it     there
 FinalFileName = Mid(FinalFileName, InStrRev(FinalFileName, "\") + 1)
'Take off the extension
FinalFileName = Left(FinalFileName, InStrRev(FinalFileName, ".") - 1)
 FinalFileName = FinalFileName

WriteTextBox = OutputPath & "\" & FinalFileName & "_" & FinalBusinessDate
'MsgBox "value is " & FinalFileName & "_" & FinalBusinessDate
 End If
 Set f = Nothing
 Set SA = Nothing

 Else
 MsgBox "Unable to process. Please ensure Business Date was entered.", vbCritical
 End If
 End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try embedding your logic in this:

```
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

My Favorite (Not mine though):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret
    Dim InitFolder As String

    InitFolder = "C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop"

    Ret = BrowseForFolder(InitFolder)

End Sub

Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
    Dim ShellApp As Object

    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
    BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set ShellApp = Nothing

    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
    Case Is = ":"
        If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Is = "\"
        If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Else
        GoTo Invalid
    End Select

    Exit Function

Invalid:
    BrowseForFolder = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub Sample()
Dim Ret
Dim InitFolder As String

```
InitFolder = "C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop"

Ret = BrowseForFolder(InitFolder)
```

End Sub

Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
Dim ShellApp As Object

```
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

On Error Resume Next
BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
On Error GoTo 0

Set ShellApp = Nothing

Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
Case Is = ":"
    If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
Case Is = "\"
    If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
Case Else
    GoTo Invalid
End Select

Exit Function
```

Invalid:
BrowseForFolder = False
End Function